SQL Group By and Order by with sum
I have this query:
--10/24/24 - UNIT PRICE AND QTY SHIPPED
SELECT 
    DBO.SHIPPER.PACKLIST_ID, dbo.shipper.SHIPPED_DATE,   
    DBO.SHIPPER.CUST_ORDER_ID, dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.SHIPPED_QTY, 
    dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE, 
    dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.SHIPPED_QTY * dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE AS TOTAL
FROM
    DBO.SHIPPER
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.SHIPPER_LINE on dbo.SHIPPER.PACKLIST_ID = dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.PACKLIST_ID
WHERE
    dbo.shipper.SHIPPED_DATE BETWEEN dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
                                 AND dateadd(m, datediff(m, -1, GetDate()), 0)
ORDER BY 
    dbo.shipper.SHIPPED_DATE 

Which returns the following results (abbreviated for discussion)
PACKLIST_ID DATE        CUST_ORDER_ID TOTAL
-----------------------------------------------------
57976       2024-10-01  C24807        3710.0000000000
57979       2024-10-01  C24860        130.0000000000
58104       2024-10-01  C24941        375.0000000000
58104       2024-10-01  C24941        1925.0000000000
58104       2024-10-01  C24941        0.0000000000
58104       2024-10-01  C24941        0.0000000000
58104       2024-10-01  C24941        0.0000000000
58104       2024-10-01  C24941        0.0000000000
58153       2024-10-04  C24923        780.0000000000
58152       2024-10-07  C24923        -6240.0000000000

What I would like to have is
PACKLIST_ID DATE        CUST_ORDER_ID  TOTAL
--------------------------------------------------------
57976       2024-10-01  C24807        3710.0000000000
57979       2024-10-01  C24860        130.0000000000
58104       2024-10-01  C24941        2300.0000000000
58153       2024-10-04  C24923        780.0000000000
58152       2024-10-07  C24923        -6240.0000000000

How can I get the sum for each CUST_ORDER_ID? There are also times when CUST_ORDER_ID is the same but the PACKLIST_ID are different and will need to keep those separate.

abbreviated for discussion is a bad idea. Make sure the specified result and the query match (same set of columns etc.)

If you want the sum of values, what's wrong with SUM? What about your attempt using a GROUP BY didn't work? What was that attempt?

Add a line to Group BY PACKLIST_ID, DATE,   CUST_ORDER_ID.   In the SELECT use SUM(dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.SHIPPED_QTY * dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE) as Total

FYI, as I note here, 3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the FROM and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Why are your results missing dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.SHIPPED_QTY  and dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE ?

What DBMS are you using? Please add the appropriate tag - sql-server, mysql, oracle, etc. The answer below might work for some DBMS, but not others. Adding the DBMS tag will also increase visibility to the intended group.

You need a complete [mre] i.e. you need to provide sample raw data then when queried returns the desired results.

@jarlh Noted. Just didn't want to fill the page with hundreds of lines

@ThomA using SUM now. Thanks for the direction. The GROUP BY I was a little unclear about, but I think I have it worked out now.

@BartMcEndree I dropped those two from my query and should have updated it. Just need the total.

Here you can use Group By clause.
Giving you simple example:
Orders
  id   item    cust_id    amount
  1   Keyboard     4        450
  2   Mouse        4        300
  3   Monitor      3      12000
  4   Keyboard     1        400
  5   Mousepad     2        250
  6   Mouse        4        120
  7   Mousepad     4        260
  8   Keyboard     1        410
  9   Monitor      4      11260

here I have to find sum of items where there is a same customer.
So this will be solution for above:
SELECT order_id, item, sum(amount) as Total, cust_id
FROM Orders
group by
    item, 
    cust_id;

Here in your case you can modify your query as below:
SELECT 
  DBO.SHIPPER.PACKLIST_ID, 
  dbo.shipper.SHIPPED_DATE, 
  DBO.SHIPPER.CUST_ORDER_ID, 
  dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.SHIPPED_QTY, 
  dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE, 
  SUM(dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.SHIPPED_QTY * dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM  
  DBO.SHIPPER
INNER JOIN 
  dbo.SHIPPER_LINE on dbo.SHIPPER.PACKLIST_ID = dbo.SHIPPER_LINE.PACKLIST_ID
WHERE 
  dbo.shipper.SHIPPED_DATE BETWEEN dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
  AND 
  dateadd(m, datediff(m, -1, GetDate()), 0)
GROUP BY 
    DBO.SHIPPER.PACKLIST_ID, 
    DBO.SHIPPER.CUST_ORDER_ID
ORDER BY 
  dbo.shipper.SHIPPED_DATE;

I hope this will help you.

GROUP BY isn't a "function", it's a clause, like WHERE and SELECT.

Don't you need to include all non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY (like order_id or dbo.shipper.SHIPPED_DATE? Or is this DBMS-specific?

I'd expect an error here, at least if MS SQL Server is used. (@TN, just like you commented.)
